# Retrieving Fragment by using Fragment Tag

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment

I am getting `NullPointerException` when retrieving a `Fragment` by its tag defined during its addition via `SupportFragmentManager`.

Here's the code:

```
 FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentOne,FRAGMENT_ONE_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    FragmentOne fragmentOneInstance = (FragmentOne) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_ONE_TAG);
    Log.i("Fragment One Instance: ", fragmentOneInstance.getTag());
```

Error report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.demo.fragment/com.ms.android.demo.fragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: What line does the NullPointer occur? The log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to wait until the transaction is executed. You can't run it immediately it after you add the fragment to the transaction.

`.commit();` is an asynchronous call.

From the documentation

> Schedules a commit of this transaction. The commit does not happen
>   immediately; it will be scheduled as work on the main thread to be
>   done the next time that thread is ready.

As a test, you can run  `executePendingTransactions ()` to execute immediately any pending operation.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment transactions are asynchronous task and when you commit, it dose not mean it is added immediately so you must call `executePendingTransactions()` if you want the transaction happens right away

```
FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragmentOne,FRAGMENT_ONE_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```